# Migrating to FCM issue adding to console

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

After having issues with crashes in Android O and also seeing that GCM is fully deprecated we are trying to migrate to FCM. Keep in mind I did zero of the setup on this project, so I'm just trying to follow the migration guide. Our server side team is very busy right now, so I'm trying to make it as easy as I can for them.

So someone gave me owner permissions on the Google APIs dashboard for the project, where I can see that Google Cloud Messaging is enabled. So I gave owner permissions to an account we now use for all of our mobile online accounts and consoles.

Then I logged into the Firebase console, but when I click "add project" I do not have the option to import the existing GCM project, as the docs seem to say I should. It also doesn't show up for my personal work account either, even though it is also an "owner" account. I was really hoping to migrate this way so that we might not have to get new api keys.

However, I do see in the Google APIs dashboard that I can "enable" FCM from there. Will this create the Firebase project for me and if so will it generate new keys or can we use the old ones?

OR is it actually better to just create an entirely new FCM project?

Comment: Hey drawinfinity. Tested this out and can confirm that this is the behavior. However, I can't say for certain that this is the expected behavior. The *Owner* role is supposed to provide full access to the project. I suggest reaching out to Google/Firebase Support about this. Cheers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue is focused on a Google Service that programming isn't necessarily the main issue.